# Styling a set of images with text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a set of images/text look uniform, but the images are not the same resolution.  I have a set of them like this:

```css
.QuickLink {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #9FAFEC;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 4px;
  padding: 2px;
  height: 160px;
}

.QuickLink img {
  width: 80px;
  margin: auto;
}

.QuickLink a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="QuickLink">
  <a href="someLink.htm">
    <img src="images/Directory.jpg" title="Directory">
    <br> Directory
  </a>
</div>
```

What I'm looking for is a set of rectangles where the image is vertical aligned to the middle and the text is to the bottom. The following gets me close but I'm not sure how to do the vertical alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1** (recommended)

```
.QuickLink {
    position: relative;
}

.QuickLink a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
.QuickLink {
    display: table;
    float: left;    // if you want them to align horizontally
}

.QuickLink a {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Solution 3** (might have browser compatibility problem)

```
.QuickLink {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -moz-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

If you want to align `.QuickLink` horizontally, wrap them inside a container.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="QuickLink">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

and set the container like so:

```
.container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -moz-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: Very thorough, I'll use your first solution. If I want the text to position at the bottom, I need to wrap that, right?

Answer (score 1):

By adjusting the display to inline-flex as well as setting the top and bottom margin to auto on the anchor tag, I was able to achieve what you're looking for.

Check out [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ymv6bL7s/3/)

```
 <div class="QuickLink" > 
        <a href="someLink.htm">
             <img src="http://images.fonearena.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Lenovo-p780-camera-sample-10.jpg" title="Directory">
             <br>
             Directory
        </a>
    </div>

 <div class="QuickLink" > 
        <a href="someLink.htm">
             <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmzMFjujgib4Md4MHoGD4VoIDwqjaG3DDrylUns_rY8dgSuybA" title="Info">
             <br>
             Info
        </a>
    </div>
.QuickLink
    {
        display: inline-flex;
    justify-content:center;
        border:2px solid #9FAFEC ;
        border-radius:4px;
        text-align: center;
        width:100px;

        margin-top:4px;
        padding:2px;
        height:160px;
    }

    .QuickLink img
    {
      height:50px;
        width:auto;
    }

    .QuickLink a 
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color:black;
        margin:auto 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using fixed height for the wrapper you can use `position:absolute` on the a tags. They are positioned with top left 50% and then compensate for the height of the a tag using transform:

https://jsfiddle.net/ymv6bL7s/7/

```css
.QuickLink
{
  display: inline-block;
  border:2px solid #9FAFEC ;
  border-radius:4px;
  text-align: center;
  width:100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top:4px;
  padding:2px;
  height:160px;
  position:relative;
}

.QuickLink img
{
  width:80px;
  margin: auto;
}  

.QuickLink a 
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:black;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="QuickLink" > 
  <a href="someLink.htm">
     <img src="http://images.fonearena.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Lenovo-p780-camera-sample-10.jpg" title="Directory">
     <br>
      Directory
  </a>
</div>

<div class="QuickLink" > 
  <a href="someLink.htm">
     <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmzMFjujgib4Md4MHoGD4VoIDwqjaG3DDrylUns_rY8dgSuybA" title="Info">
     <br>
     Info
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The fixed height was more or less me trying to work around, I'm not attached to it so long as they all end up the same height.

Comment: Yong Quan answer has all the solutions you could need, with the correct browser prefixes as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632880/styling-a-set-of-images-with-text/44633677#44633677

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox in order to do that:

```
.QuickLink a 
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;

  text-decoration: none;
  color:black;
}
```

However, now images won't be perfectly in the center of div because the text on the bottom takes some place. If you want to change that you need to do some tweaks in HTML ie. wrap text in `SPAN` tags, set them absolute position and add a relative position to `A` tag:

```
.QuickLink span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.QuickLink a {
  [...]
  position: relative
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JacobDesight/ymv6bL7s/8/